# Image recognition - car detection

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, gis

How do I classify the number of cars in an image from a 4k aerial camera attached to DJI drone at 400 feet ? Will not allow me to attach an image to my post.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  What have you tried so far?  Please use the guidelines to improve your question so that member can more readily help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). You will find some pretrained models on datasets such as [COCO](http://cocodataset.org/#home). Definitely they should be able to recognize cars but I have no idea whether that would work with aerial pictures where you would only see the top of the cars. You can always generate yourself a dataset and fine tune a pretrained model.